# Using PSTricks with babel/fontspec in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, pstricks, babel, overleaf

Building on the example [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/using-pstricks-with-pdflatex-on-overleaf/dktntcxgyqmy), I tried to see if I can make PSTricks work in LuaLaTeX in Overleaf.

This is my `latexmkrc` file

```
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = '^/(CreationDate|ModDate|ID) ';
```

This is my `main.tex` file, with the babel and fontspec lines commented.

```
\def\jobname{main}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
% \usepackage{babel}
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \babelfont{rm}{CharisSIL}
\begin{document}
\section{Using pstricks with lualatex}
\psset{subgriddiv=0}
\SpecialCoor
\psset{griddots=5,subgriddiv=0,gridlabels=0pt}
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)\psgrid
  \pscircle(2,2){2}
  \qdisk(!2  2 70 sin mul add 2 -2 70 cos mul add){4pt}
  \pscoil[coilarm=3mm,coilwidth=3mm,linecolor=red]{-}%
         (2,0)(!2 2 70 sin mul add 2 -2 70 cos mul add)
  \rput(3.6,1.6){$m$}
  \rput(2.8,1){$k$}
  \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5pt]{<-}(0,2)(2,2)
  \rput(1,2.2){$r$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

This works fine on LuaLaTex compiler with TeXLive version 2020 and I see the pspicture as expected.

The problem is when I uncomment the three lines

```
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelfont{rm}{CharisSIL}
```

The compiler complies (with warnings, but no errors) and generates a PDF but the pspicture is missing. These are the warnings I see.

```
Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: Creation of main-autopp.dvi failed. This warning occured on input line 124.
‪/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auto-pst-pdf/auto-pst-pdf.sty, 124‬
Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: Could not create main-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted. This warning occured on input line 124.
‪/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auto-pst-pdf/auto-pst-pdf.sty, 124‬
Package pst-pdf Warning: pspicture No. 1 undefined.
‪main.tex‬
Package pst-pdf Warning: File `main-pics.pdf' not found. Use the following commands to create it: ---------------------------------------------------- latex main.tex dvips -o main-pics.ps main.dvi ps2pdf main-pics.ps ---------------------------------------------------- . [1
```

So it seems something clashes when I load babel/fontspec with pstricks on LuaLaTex? Any workaround to make them work together?

Comment: `babel` loads `fontspec`, so no need to load it twice. Compiles OK then. With a second `fontspec` loaded, the pst picture disappears. I don't have Overleaf.

Comment: Note: the log has multiple messages "Non-PDF Special ignored!" which you may have to get resolved, depending on what you want to do. Note also: `auto-pst-pdf` runs pdfTeX in the background (via shell-escape), so pdfTeX could be a potential factor for the non-Specials.

Comment: I don't see how you could get this to work, pstricks requires you to use a latex/dvips/ps2pdf workflow and that can be done with very simple documents but not if you use type1 fonts.  Just generate the picture using pstricks with _latex_ in a separate project and then include the generated pdf into your lualatex document

Answer (score 2):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pspdf={-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY}]{auto-pst-pdf}
 \usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdf
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \babelfont{rm}{CharisSIL}
\else
  \usepackage{pst-all}
  \usepackage{pst-text}
\fi
\begin{document}
....
```

And you can try:

```
\usepackage[pspdf={-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY}]{auto-pst-pdf-lua}
```

it uses `xeLatex` for PSTricks, but does not work for all node examples. And `latexmk` needs tobe run with

```
latexmk -pdflua -latexoption=-shell-escape <file>
```

don't know how this can be set in the config file for `latexmk`

Answer (score 0):

The `dvips` step of `auto-pst-pdf` would error out because it can't use `fontspec`. You might try omitting `\babelfont` during `dvips` using `ifluatex`:

```latex
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
\babelfont{rm}{CharisSIL}
\fi
```

though this does mean your PStricks drawings won't use the same font as your body text.